# В нешкольной / не школьной обстановке общаться интереснее

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> В нешкольной обстановке общаться интереснее.

> В не школьной обстановке общаться интереснее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно написать слитно:

*В **нешкольной** обстановке общаться интереснее*.

Значение утвердительное. Плюс прилагательное является определением, поэтому пишем слитно. (Было б сказуемым — писали бы раздельно.)

Всë написано в [пунктах 2 — 5](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77).

Comment: У вас вроде бы "писали бы раздельно"?   Сказуемое:  Обстановка была нешкольная, свободная,  так всегда интереснее.  Или раздельно?

Comment: Думаю, раздельно, раз сказуемое. А сказуемое такое: _была не школьная, свободная_.

Comment: А так: У них в школе обстановка совершенно нешкольная.  Тоже раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*В **нешкольной** обстановке общаться интереснее.*

ПАС по ред Лопатина:  **[§148](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-4%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5)**

2. Если существительные и прилагательные в сочетании с **не обозначают непринадлежность к какому-либо разряду лиц или явлений, напр.**: неврачи, нефраниузы, немарксисты, нехристиане, неспециалисты, немосквичи, нерусские, недемократы, непоэты, нетермины, неметаллы, нестихи; Нерусский взглянет без любви / На эту бледную, в крови, / Кнутом иссеченную музу (Некр.); Неврач не разберётся в этом; Неспециалистам доклад понравился; Неегиптолог его не поймёт; Нематематику не решить этой задачи; Нелингвист не напишет такой диктант; **неакадемические институты, непищевые добавки, невоенные отрасли.**

**Примеры**

[Нешкольное образование в России: быть или не быть](https://school4you.ru/homeschooling-in-russia-to-be-or-not-to-be/)

[Нешкольная поэзия](https://svlib.ru/novosti/anonsyi/2023/neshkolnaya-poeziya)

Интересно: [Словарь русского языка XVIII в.](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/14/slf12807.htm)

**НЕШКОЛЬНЫЙ**, ая, ое. Неученый, необразованный. Граф на тѣ слова аки бы сердитуя рекл: како я с ним бездельником и нешкольным человѣком немогу от писания диспуты отправити, чем он силен? Д. Тв. 9.